# Trying Graph Explorer to find out Intune managedAppRegistrtaion per user

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to figure out the `managedAppRegistration` of a user using Microsoft Grpah Explorer. But it is not going through. Can someone suggest solution?

Here's the request I am trying:

> GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/user@domain.com/managedAppRegistrations
>
> GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/user@domain.com/registeredDevice

None of this seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

according to [docs](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/intune_mam_managedappregistration_list) you need subscription for for using Graph API for intunes service. Could you check if you have subscription and login with correct account info to use graph api.

> Note: Using the Microsoft Graph APIs to configure Intune controls and
>   policies still requires that the Intune service is [correctly licensed](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/cloud-platform/microsoft-intune-pricing)
>   by the customer.